# polylang plugin shows all site pages on one page when switching to second language

Tags: polylang

I am trying to switch to a second language using polylang plugin in my Wordpress test site.

I don't have relevant code to show, I haven't identified problem code associated with this error.

What I expect is to find myself on the Home page equivalent in the second language no matter which English page I was on previously.

Instead I am taken to the Spanish version of the About page, not Home page equivalent. Also, the page content is made up of not just that page's content but all of the content from every page on the site is stacked on top of each other - including old versions of pages.

If I subsequently click on the Spanish menu which displays as expected, the next page displays perfectly. When I click back to the About page (the page previous acting as a site catch-all) everything is as it should be. So the problem only manifests on the initial switch to a second language.

Switching back to English does not cause the problem to reoccur, everything is fine in this case. It is only when initially switching from English (site primary language) to Spanish that the problem occurs.

I am using the 'X' Wordpress theme for this 'local' version of my site. My Wordpress & free polylang versions are up to date. 
Any help with this problem would be much appreciated. 
Thanks, Brent.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a solution for my problem.
This isn't the most elegant solution but I need something that works now so here goes.

I noticed that when switching to Spanish I was taken to the page: http://localhost/www.ecia.com/es/ i.e. no specific page, fine if I had an index.php file in that location but I don't. The result is I am taken to the page with the bloated content.

My work around was, use a redirection for that URL to the page I want the switcher to go to i.e. instead of http://localhost/www.ecia.com/es - I redirect to http://localhost/www.ecia.com/es/casa

This is not the best fix, but I have found it difficult going any deeper into how Polylang plugin works so it will suffice for my purposes.

Brent

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by:

Go to language/setting/url settigs

Uncheck "Hide URL language information for default language "